# Can't see USB Drive in Advanced Boot menu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, usb

Was going to dualboot my Lenovo P50s with Ubuntu alongside already installed Windows 10 today. I made a bootable USB drive and entered the Advanced Boot menu (shift-click on reboot), earlier I have been familiar with that this will show the drives which you can select of. Today at the unit i was working on I was not presented with the drives, only with the standard choices of the Advanced Boot Menu, anyone familiar what the reason might be?

Of course I can change the actual bootorder and go through that, but Im curioius what might be the reason I don't see the drive throughe the Advanced Boot Menu.

Br.
akvisvik

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows using UEFI or using the Legacy\MBR\CSM BIOS.
If the BIOS is set to CSM disabled, then the system will not see non-UEFI files - so your USB drive must be formatted as FAT32 and must contain the correct boot files which includes a \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI file which is the default boot file for a USB drive.
If your Windows 10 is UEFI + GPT partitions, then you will have to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode also.